# Remover linhas duplicadas numa consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando fazer um consulta SQL onde retorna a ultima mensagens trocada entre usuarios (minha conta por exemplo) e quem conversei... independente se foi enviada ou recebida a ultima conversa.

O código que estou usando trás as enviadas e recebidas no caso repetindo o usuario, gostaria que saber como faço não repetir agrupar somente a minha ultima conversa com quem conversei independente se a mensagem foi enviada ou recebida.

```
SELECT distinct * FROM mensagens inner join usuarios on de = id_user where para LIKE '$sessao' 
union SELECT distinct * FROM mensagens inner join usuarios on para = id_user where de LIKE '$sessao' 
group by id_user  order by  id asc
```

Tabela mensagens:

```
id - de - para - mensagem
```

Tabela usuarios:

```
id_user - nome
```

Comment: Em `$sessao` recebe o seu próprio ID?

Comment: Jonatan, é legal indentar o SQL igual o @Jader faz na resposta abaixo, fica bem mais fácil entender o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode buscar as ultimas mensagens quando `de` ou `para` forem igual ao ID desejado, ordenar por ID de mensagem decrescente (considere criar um campo data e hora) e fazer dois left joins para pegar os nomes `de` e `para`, assim:

**Exemplo para pegar as ultimas mensagens do usuário ID 1:**

```
SELECT m.id, de.nome de, para.nome para, m.mensagem
FROM mensagens m
LEFT JOIN usuarios de ON de.id_user = m.de
LEFT JOIN usuarios para ON para.id_user = m.para
WHERE m.de = '1' OR m.para = '1' ORDER BY m.id DESC;
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b04a/1)

---

Reli a sua pergunta com mais atenção e segue abaixo como pegar a ultima conversa trocada com a outra pessoa, independente se foi recebida ou enviada:

**Agora supondo que o usuário logado é o ID 4:**

```
SELECT m.id, de.nome de, para.nome para, m.mensagem
FROM mensagens m
LEFT JOIN usuarios de ON de.id_user = m.de
LEFT JOIN usuarios para ON para.id_user = m.para
WHERE
(m.de = (SELECT if (de = '4', para, de) FROM mensagens WHERE de = '4' or para='4' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
and
m.para = '4')
or
(m.de = '4'
and
m.para = (SELECT if (para = '4', de, para) FROM mensagens WHERE de = '4' or para='4' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
) ORDER BY m.id ASC;
```

Obs.: *Trocar todos os `'4'` pelo id do usuário logado*.

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd1bd/1)

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um campo de data e/ou hora na tabela mensagens , e coloca um `LIMIT 1` quando for fazer um `SELECT` nas mensagens